# Check the output of "make" and exit bash script if it fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm a nube to more than just bash, however; I've written a bash script that will execute my cmake, make, and c++ executable.

```
#! /bin/bash
cmake .
make
./pcl_visualizer_demo   <-- This is my executable
```

This works great except when my code fails to compile it executes the old executable and leaves me with a mess. I was hoping to put the output of make into an if statement that only runs the executable when make is successful. I've tried a great many bash things from other posts here on stackoverflow. Some of the problems seem to be that the output of make is not a string for example:

```
OUTPUT = make
echo $OUTPUT
```

gives:

```
[100%] Built target pcl_visualizer_demo
```

But fails to work with:

```
if [`expr match "$OUTPUT" '[100%] -eq 5]; then ./pcl_visulizer_demo; fi
```

Not to mention I think there may be more than one thing wrong with this line. I also tried:

```
if [diff <(echo "$OUTPUT") <(echo '[100%] Built target pcl_visualizer_demo' -n]; then ./pcl_visulizer_demo; fi
```

Again it could be that I'm not implementing it right. Any help

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Check+the+output+of+make+and+exit+bash+script+if+it+fails

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just check the exit code of make:

```
cmake . || exit 1
make || exit 1
./pcl_visualizer_demo
```

Comment: Thanks it works great! Sadly  I'm not allowed to up vote you because I have no reputation :(.

Comment: Great, thanks God that somebody didn't rely on the google comment under the question. :) Can you explain a bit how this works? `make` will return 0 when everything is fine and because of short circuiting `exit` won't be executed? In the failure case it will, but what is that `1` after `exit`? The return value of the script?

Comment: @gsamaras: Yes, yes, yes. :-)

Answer (score 12):

You could use

```
set -e
```

at the beginning of your shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cmake .
make
./pcl_visualizer_demo
```

From 'help set'

```
-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

Which by default means: on any error

Answer (score 5):

You should probably check the exit code of make e.g.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully made"
else
  echo "Could not compile" >&2
fi
```

and exit appropriately. By convention, an exit code of 0 indicates success. If you have multiple executables and you want to bail out if any return a non-zero exit code, you can tell bash to do just that with the `-e` option e.g.

```
  #!/usr/bin/bash -e
```

Just make sure that the executables (`make` and `cmake`) follow this convention. See [here](http://bencane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-bash-scripts/) for more information on exit codes.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly as it turns out make returns 0 weather or not it fails. choroba suggested the or command and it works great. I'm not allowed to up vote you because I have no reputation :(.

Comment: I would expect make *not* to return 0 upon failure, and the || construct above relies on the exit code being not 0. So I would recheck your exit code (I think Choroba's solution would work nicely, of course)

Comment: Yes you are correct. Your method also works. I used echo $? to test the output of make and it gives me 0 both when it works and when it fails. Why am I getting this printed to the terminal yet your code works when pasted in full?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to determine what the 'exit status' of your previous bash command was using '$?'.  Usually, a build that did not succeed will exit with a non zero status.  Double check that this is true in your case by echo-ing '$?'

Then use an normal if statement to proceed correctly.

> $? reads the exit status of the last command executed. After a
>   function returns, $? gives the exit status of the last command
>   executed in the function. This is Bash's way of giving functions a
>   "return value."
>   . . .
>   After a script terminates, a $? from the command-line gives the exit
>   status of the script, that is, the last command executed in the
>   script, which is, by convention, 0 on success or an integer in the
>   range 1 - 255 on error.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: What a useful command. Thanks. Sadly as it turns out make returns 0 weather or not it fails. choroba suggested the or command and it works great. I'm not allowed to up vote you because I have no reputation :(.

Comment: As Brian Agnew pointed out. The output of make is not always 0. Somehow when I echo $? I always get 0. I'm not sure why.