# Check return value of g++

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gcc

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024525/how-to-check-if-gcc-has-failed-returned-a-warning-or-succeeded-in-bash), which suggests the following compilation check:

```
installCheck () {
  if g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv; then
    return 1
  else
    rm check_opencv
    return 0
  fi
}

if installCheck $0; then
  echo "OpenCV already installed, skipping"
  exit 0
fi
```

However, running this script gives:

```
check_opencv.cpp:2:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
rm: check_opencv: No such file or directory
OpenCV already installed, skipping
```

which is wrong. Then I change to this:

```
installCheck () {
  g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
```

and it works fine:

```
check_opencv.cpp:2:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Cloning into 'opencv-2.4.9'...
```

Why is that? Because of some behavior of `[[` or `g++`?

Someone in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919778/check-the-output-of-make-and-exit-bash-script-if-it-fails) says that "Sadly as it turns out make returns 0 weather or not it fails." Shouldn't `g++` always return non-zero value when it fails? Maybe I miss something obvious, so please clarify for me. Thank you very much!

Update: it turns out that I understand bash wrongly. A return value of 0 evaluates to true in bash, which is contradictory to what I thought before. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933843/why-0-is-true-but-false-is-1-in-the-shell) helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv; then
  return 1
```

will return failure (1) if the compilation *succeeds*. Apparently, you wanted to return failure if the compilation failed, which would be:

```
if ! g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv; then
  return 1
```

Or you could just put the true and false branches in the correct order:

```
installCheck () {
  if g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv; then
    rm check_opencv
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
```

I don't see anywhere in the linked question where it suggests the code which you proposed.

I suppose that your intention was to avoid contaminating the filesystem if the compilation succeeds, since the compilation itself is the only test needed. You could also achieve this with:

```
installCheck () {
  g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv
  local rv=$?
  rm -f check_opencv
  return rv
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between   "if [[ ! $(g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv) ]]; then" and "  if ! g++ check_opencv.cpp -o check_opencv; then"? The latter one does not work when opencv is already installed. Thanks!

Comment: @YunshengBai: They are completely different things. The first one is not very meaningful: it succeeds if the `g++` command does not print anything to `stdout` (which is normal since `g++` normally prints errors to `stderr`). The second one tests if `g++` returned a failure code. You'll need to be clearer about what you mean by "the latter one does not work".

Comment: Thank you! I am completely new to bash programming, and I will learn it.

Answer (score 0):

`if cmd; ...` is "true" if cmd is successful i.e. exit status of cmd is 0 - it is logically equivalent to `cmd; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; ...`